# How can I profile the TLB hits and TLB misses in ubuntu

Tags: c++, performance, linux-kernel, monitoring

I have written a simple C++ program using for-loop to print the numbers from 1 to 100. I want to find the number of TLB hits and misses occurring for the particular program while running. Is there any possibility to get this data?

I am using Ubuntu. I have used perf tool. But it is producing different result in different times. I am very confused what part of my code is leading to such a huge number TLB hits, TLB misses and cache misses.

Ofcourse there might be other processes running simultaneously like Ubuntu GUI. But, does this result includes those process too?
command I used: perf stat -e dTLB-loads -e dTPerformance counter stats for './hellocc':

result: first time--

```
       909,822 dTLB-loads                                                  
         2,023 dTLB-misses               #    0.22% of all dTLB cache hits 
         4,512 cache-misses                                                

   0.006821182 seconds time elapsed
```

LB-misses ./hellocc

result: Second time--    Performance counter stats for './hellocc':

```
       907,810 dTLB-loads                                                  
         2,045 dTLB-misses               #    0.23% of all dTLB cache hits 
         4,533 cache-misses                                                

   0.006780635 seconds time elapsed
```

My simple code:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
int main
{    
    cout << "hello" << "\n";    
    for(int i=1; i <= 100; i = i + 1)    
        cout<< i << "\t" ;    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, console output is remarkably complicated (and thus slow) code.  99+% of the code is probably in the IO.

Answer (score 4):

One way you could simulate this is using [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html), a part of valgrind.

> Cachegrind simulates how your program interacts with a machine's cache hierarchy and (optionally) branch predictor. It simulates a machine with independent first-level instruction and data caches (I1 and D1), backed by a unified second-level cache (L2). This exactly matches the configuration of many modern machines.

While it's not your hardware, which I don't think you can get to, it's a good stand-in.

Answer (score 2):

The cache behaviour of your program depends on what else is happening on your system at the time.

On a Linux system there are many processes running, such as the X server and window manager, the terminal, your editor, various daemon processes, and whatever else you have running (such as a web browser).

Depending on the vagaries of the scheduler, and the demands these other programs place on your system, your program's data may or may not stay in cache (the scheduler may even page your process entirely to the swap file), so the number of cache misses will vary depending on the other applications running.